# Why doesn't random effects in python match stata?

Tags: python, panel, stata

I'm trying to implement a random effects model in pandas, but the coefficients on my regression don't match my output from Stata. I'm using a panel of airline routes and ticket prices. Here's my Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.stats.plm as plm

airline = pd.read_csv("C:...\Airline.csv")
airline['constant'] = 1.0
airline = airline.set_index(['route', 'time'])
airlinePanel = airline.to_panel()


airlineRE = plm.PanelOLS(y = airlinePanel['lnMktfare'], x=airlinePanel[['constant', 'mktdistance', 'passengers', 'percentAA', 'percentAS',
            'percentDL', 'percentHA', 'percentNK', 'percentUA', 'percentUS', 'percentWN']],
            intercept= True, time_effects=True, dropped_dummies=True, verbose=True)
print airlineRE
```

and output:

```
 -------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~  <mktdistance> + <passengers> + <percentAA>
         + <percentAS> + <percentDL> + <percentHA> + <percentNK> + <percentUA>
         + <percentUS> + <percentWN>

Number of Observations:         88000
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   1010

R-squared:         0.2357
Adj R-squared:     0.2268

Rmse:              0.3762

F-stat (10, 86990):    26.5805, p-value:     0.0000

Degrees of Freedom: model 1009, resid 86990

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mktdistance   0.0002     0.0000     125.73     0.0000     0.0002     0.0002
passengers   -0.0000     0.0000     -33.44     0.0000    -0.0000    -0.0000
percentAA     0.1290     0.0045      28.85     0.0000     0.1202     0.1378
percentAS     0.1079     0.0067      16.06     0.0000     0.0947     0.1211
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
percentDL     0.2682     0.0033      81.44     0.0000     0.2617     0.2746
percentHA    -0.1609     0.1439      -1.12     0.2635    -0.4430     0.1211
percentNK    -0.4412     0.0144     -30.73     0.0000    -0.4693    -0.4131
percentUA     0.2156     0.0041      52.70     0.0000     0.2076     0.2236
percentUS     0.1839     0.0034      54.19     0.0000     0.1772     0.1905
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
percentWN    -0.0658     0.0033     -19.93     0.0000    -0.0722    -0.0593
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

First, before I move on to the Stata output, does anyone know why I'm not getting an intercept term even when I put `intercept = True`? Even if I add this manually to the regression equation Python estimates the constant as follows:

```
-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constant     0.0000        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
```

And none of the other estimates changed. Now for the Stata code:

```
import delimited "C:...\Airline.csv", clear
xtset route time
xtreg lnmktfare mktdistance passengers percent*
```

And the Stata output:

```
Random-effects GLS regression                   Number of obs     =     88,000
Group variable: route                          Number of groups  =      1,000

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.2983                                         min =         88
     between = 0.6943                                         avg =       88.0
     overall = 0.3154                                         max =         88

                                                Wald chi2(97)     =   39530.19
corr(u_i, X)   = 0 (assumed)                    Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 lnmktfare   |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 mktdistance |   .0002374   1.78e-06   133.40   0.000     .0002339    .0002409
 passengers  |  -.0000382   8.90e-07   -42.91   0.000    -.0000399   -.0000364

 percentAA   |   .1340237   .0058275    23.00   0.000      .122602    .1454454
 percentAS   |   .1159311    .006403    18.11   0.000     .1033815    .1284807
 percentDL   |   .2689447   .0039186    68.63   0.000     .2612644     .276625
 percentHA   |  -.0637648   .1378896    -0.46   0.644    -.3340235    .2064939
 percentNK   |  -.4974099   .0131605   -37.80   0.000     -.523204   -.4716158
 percentUA   |   .1653212   .0055116    30.00   0.000     .1545187    .1761236
 percentUS   |   .1784333   .0046914    38.03   0.000     .1692383    .1876283
 percentWN   |  -.1531444   .0041407   -36.98   0.000    -.1612601   -.1450286
     _cons   |   4.893488    .011821   413.97   0.000     4.870319    4.916657
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   sigma_u   |  .02593863
   sigma_e   |  .36056598
       rho   |  .00514853   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know why the coefficients are slightly off between the two programs but it's a large enough difference to worry me about the accuracy of pandas. My main questions are (1) why don't I get an intercept term from pandas? and (2) why don't the coefficients match across the two packages. Note, I've compared OLS, Logit, and IV2SLS models between Python and Stata the results match perfectly, which makes me think there might be something wrong with the implementation of the random effects model in pandas. I'm running Python 2.7.9 inside IPython 3.0.0, and Stata 14.

Comment: Maybe a different random effects transformation is used in the different programms? There are at least four different transformations (see e.g. http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plm/docs/plm under "random.method")

Answer (score 1):

Your python code is doing fixed effects. You can see this from the degrees of freedom, which is over 1000 in your python output and under 100 in your Stata output. Unlike fixed effects, random effects aren't treated as parameters to be estimated - they are assumed to be uncorrelated with X but with a particular error structure that makes RE more efficient than pooled OLS.